# Position:Fixed and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

For the last few days I have been designing a layout for my website based on some art I drew. The layout turned out great on Chrome and Firefox and then I checked IE and it looked horrible.

I know that only IE 7 supports position fixed but it's not working for me... and I have tried about ten different codes that should allow the image to move to the bottom right but with how many layers my layout has, it does not work.

http://lindsiria.net/

As you can see, I have two problems on IE. My whole layout is moved over and my main banner image is not at the bottom right. I was wondering if someone could look at this code and help me figure out a solution for this annoying error. Hope I posted this right.

```
<code>
<!-- language: lang-css -->

* { margin:0;}
body {
    background-color:#2397b6;
    background-image: url("mainbackgroundrepeat1"); 
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position:bottom;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    height:100%;
    }

a:link { color:#2b8c56;}
a:visited {color:#2b8c56;}
a:hover {color:#f0faef;}

#banner_wrap{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    margin-left:800px;
    width:500px;
    z-index:-1; 
    height: 353px;

}

#logo_wrap {
    position:absolute;
    width:600px;
        margin-left:200px;
    margin-top:2px;
 }

#wrap {
    position:absolute;
    width: 580px;
    min-height:100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 180px 0 -353px 180px;
    background-color:#b2d6df;
    border: 10px solid #2b8c56;
    text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
 }

#footer {
    font-size: .75em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: left;

}
/* START NAVIGATION */

#centeredmenu {
   float:left;
   width: 600px;
   margin-left:180px;
   margin-top:100px;
   background:#b2d6df;
   border: 10px solid #2b8c56;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:absolute;
}
#centeredmenu ul {
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   left:50%;
   text-align:center;
}
#centeredmenu ul li {
   display:block;
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   right:50%;
}
#centeredmenu ul li a {
   display:block;
   width: 77px;
   padding:9px;
   margin:0 12px 0 12px;
   border-bottom: 4px solid #5bc668;
   color:#000;
   text-decoration:none;
   font-variant:small-caps;
   letter-spacing:2px;
   font-weight:500;
   line-height:.7em;
}
#centeredmenu ul li a:hover {
   border-bottom:4px solid #f0faef;
   color:#000000;
}
/* END NAVIGATION */
</code>
```

Comment: Can some body please edit this for readability.

Comment: Thanks Soner. How do you get the @ and what does it mean?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/84qAg/

Comment: Woah. I never heard of jsfiddle but it is awesome. Thank you, I was unable to post my HTML part of my code because the site thought I was trying to upload images. Also, thank you Soner for fixing my code so it is readable. Still trying to learn how to work this site.

Comment: jsfiddle is great for allowing the community to play with and edit your code. Also makes it a lot easier for us to provide you with solutions and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mark-up` does need a bit of work but you will get a better understanding as you get more experienced. Rather then use a negative `z-index` and have the image in a `div` at the bottom of your `mark-up`, another possible solution is to wrap your page in a wrapper `div` that is larger then your page and set the `background-image` to that of your sea lion and have it `fixed` and to the left.

**See this updated, and now working version, JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/84qAg/1/**

Hope this helps and best of luck with it all.

Comment: Oh my god. It works. I would have never thought of this. Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries Lindsiria. Remember to mark the answer as correct if you believe it best answers your question/solves your problem.

Comment: Also, here are a few good resources/websites for designers alike. Articles range for newbies to experts:
http://tutorialzine.com/
http://tutsplus.com/
http://www.alistapart.com/
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/
http://css-tricks.com/
http://960.gs/

Answer (score 1):

Browsers display your website in quirks mode, this is why your layout is broken. Change your doctype to

```
<!doctype html>
```

Also, please note that absolute positioning is bad for creating layouts.

Comment: Changed it. Nothing happened. Also... I am beginning to learn that absolute positioning is bad. -sigh- This means I am going to have to redo everything I think.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to figure out what tweak would fix your problem, I would recommend a different strategy for marking up and styling your main content. First, rather than put text content directly into your divs and use break tags to separate paragraphs, put them in paragraphs. They're block elements by default and will create natural separation for your content (you're using some css reset, so you'll probably need to add some margin-bottom style to your paragraph tags.) Second, if you're going to use position: absolute, then use top:, left: etc. to position your element, not margins.

Comment: Haha, I'm an idiot. I did not realize I could just use left, right instead of margins. I ended up editing it, but it still did not fix my problem. I plan on putting my content into paragraphs but at this point I am just trying to figure out how to fix it on IE. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine what are your reasons for doing the way you are doing it. Why do you need position: fixed and absolute in your situation. Just add a div with a id of wrapper as a direct child of the body element and place all other divs inside it, give it a margin: 0 auto, to center it. Than you can also give it a position: relative and other div's inside it position: absolute for further syling. You layout looks broken even in IE9. Remove all margin-left. You have a very simple design. You could od as

```
div#wrapper
{
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Next put the image in the div#banner_wrap in the background image of the body element, Since the body element has already a fixed background image property, it will work out the same and inthis way you would not need to add another div.

Comment: I just wanted the background image to be a semi-liquid layout, expanding for larger browsers while the wolf moves down as you move down the page. I was not sure how to do it, other than this way.

Comment: No probs mate. I was there once too. Good luck. Post back for any further problems. Amazing community here, who takes the time out to help!

Comment: Okay. I think I understand what you are trying to say but I want to clarify. 

Instead of having many separate div- I should have one large div wrapper with the smaller div's inside of it? I could do this. I don't know WHY I didn't think of this...

The part I am still unsure about is where would I put the wolf image. I already have a repeating semi-liquid image in the body, wouldn't I be forced to create anything div to handle the wolf on the side of the content?

Thanks for everything so far.

Comment: There are 2 options. The first is that you edit the background-image file of the body element/tag and put the wolf image along with the background-image by joining the two image files. This would required you to use any image editing application like photoshop. Second is you put the wolf img inside a div as you have done now and place it inside the div#wrapper but below everthing elese so that it is the last element in teh normal flow of the document. Than give div#wrapper(position: relative;} and div#banner_wrap {position: absolute; bottom:0; right: 300px;}

Comment: Ahh. Understandable. I will try the second option. i cannot do the first as I want my background image to keep repeating on different screen sizes. By combining the two images, I could not do this (well I could, but that involves a whole different set of code). Thank you for clarifying. I will try tomorrow (its almost 1 am here).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change banner_wrap to

```
    #banner_wrap{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1; 
    right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;

}
```

Comment: Nope. I already tried this. It doesn't help the IE messed up version at all... and it screws up  my Chrome and Firefox. On smaller webpages, it forces the wolf underneath the content.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle I used http://jsfiddle.net/RzEBr/2/ As you said in another comment, youre probably best off rewriting the whole thing. Funny design though, and happy learning